# How long do you overcut replacement studs on a load bearing wall?

Tags: framing, studs, load-bearing, load

I'm replacing a few 2x4 studs on a load bearing wall. It's not sagging but I'm rearranging an opening and also, some of the studs are showing some damage.  I've heard specific guidance on how much longer the new studs has to be to fit snugly and carry load. I think it's 1/8" but I'm not sure and I can't find confirmation. For example, something like, "If  there's 90" between the top and bottom plate, cut a new stud to 90 1/8" and then bang it into place."

The top plate is currently braced in place, so I'm not going to lift the top plate.

Comment: How are you measuring for sag? Are you trying to keep things as is (i.e. all framing above this already appears square) or are you trying to work to a standard such as a laser level? The most likely answer is that they should just be overcut enough to require a few light taps to snug in, maybe a 1/32, but if you're trying to accomplish something more it will help to answer accurately.

Comment: Are you planning to jack the top plate up to install each stud?

Answer (score 3):

You want them barely snug, but it depends on whether there's any give in the plates. 1/8" is too much if the plates are rigidly supported, and the stud will bow or you'll do damage to the plates driving them in. If you were to replace a series of studs with new ones 1/8" oversized you'd likely lift the floor or ceiling above.

The short answer is that there are too many variables to give a specific number. Try 1/8". If they don't go in with a few whacks with a framing hammer, try half that. If you find yourself needing an 8 pound sledge, they're too long.